# How to access different tty session

Tags: linux, unix, tty, ps

I wanted to know if there is any possibility of login to other tty sessions. Someone has mistakenly changed the root su password. One of the session is already logged in as root. So any possibility for me to login to that session and change root password. My OS is RHEL 6

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think that you have to log in on an already logged in terminal?  Why is the obvious "Just go to the terminal and use it." not the answer?

Comment: I only have SSH session accessible. No GUI

Comment: I can't think of any good reason that would be doable - it would be a *massive* security risk.

Answer (score 0):

In BSD, you can use [`watch`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?watch) which snoops a given tty, e.g.

```
watch /dev/pts/0
```

> `-W` Allow write access   to observed tty.

However in Linux, `watch` command is different, and it won't be possible if the process wasn't run under multiplexer before such as `screen` or `tmux`. See also: [Reptyr: Attach a Running Process to a New Terminal](https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/01/reptyr-attach-a-running-process-to-a-new-terminal/)

It seems the only way is to debug the process (e.g. `strace`, `dtrace`/`dtruss`, [`gdb`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14731/21471), `lldb`, etc.).

See also: [How to view the output of a running process in another bash session?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58550/21471)

Comment: Those are read-only, aren't they? A better option would be TIOCSTI...

Comment: @grawity On BSD, it can be interactive. `-W - Allow write access to observed tty.`

Answer (score 0):

If the root password has been changed, I really recommend you to investigate who and why. Perhaps there is a malware installed or the system has been hijacked. Then, I suggest to boot from a CD or USB stick like SystemRescueCD, where you can change the root password.